# OpenCV built in Debug or Release mode?

Tags: c++, python-2.7, opencv, linux-mint, release-mode

I want to know **for sure** if OpenCV was built in Debug or Release Mode.

I am running Linux Mint 17.1 Rebbeca.

I installed OpenCV by Synaptic.

After searching in google and in my computer I found that one of the configuration files is OpenCVModules-release.cmake - but still I cannot say that this file was used in compilation time.

Do you know another method to check how the OpenCV was built?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try a :

```
System.out.println(Core.getBuildInformation());
```

(or, for python):

```
print cv2.getBuildInformation()
```

you should see something like:

```
 [java] General configuration for OpenCV 3.0.0-dev =====================================
 [java]   Version control:               3.0.0-beta-539-g08dd1e0
 [java] 
 [java]   Platform:
 [java]     Host:                        Linux 3.13.0-40-generic x86_64
 [java]     CMake:                       2.8.12.1
 [java]     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
 [java]     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
 [java]     Configuration:               Release
 ...
```